# UITableView blocking other views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I have a UIViewController that has a table, a text field, and a button. I created this UI in InterfaceBuilder a few years ago, so I'm coming back to it.

I've noticed if the table is on top, then the text field and button do not respond to input. However, I noticed if I put the table beneath these items, the text field and button do work.

What's going on there?

[image: table on top]

[image: table on bottom]

Comment: And you can see text field and button in run-time just fine regardless of position?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the frame of the UITableView. UITableViewControllers are dodgy territory to use if you're implementing custom UI. I would strongly suggest using a UIViewController and having a UITableView within it. If you do this, you have more control. I imagine your problem is that the UITableViewController will automatically assign the frame of the UITableView to be the height of the device, regardless of your own positioning in Interface Builder.

Try printing the frame of the UITableView on "layoutSubviews" in the UIViewController.